# ASP.NET: How to access parent list item element from linkbutton?

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, linkbutton

I have the following situation...

```
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Link</asp:LinkButton></li>
```

I'm wanting to be able to set the class (or add to the class attribute) of my list item when I click on the button.  So once I click on the LinkButton I want the code to change to something like the following...

```
<li class="selected"><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Link</asp:LinkButton></li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please share the error which you are getting....

Comment: @RahulTripathi, I'm not getting any errors. I'm trying to find out how to attempt to get this to work.

Comment: @COLDTOLD, I'm not totally against using Jquery, but would rather use the codebehind (VB.NET) of my asp.net page. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to perform this on the server, as the response will re-render the page. Thus, making JavaScript changes non-applicable:

```
Dim parent As HtmlControl = LinkButton1.Parent
parent.Attributes("class") = "selected"
```

Comment: When you say to perform this on the server how am I to do that? It currently doesn't work with the code above. I'm guessing that is because the page isn't refreshed?

Comment: if it isn't refreshing, and it was designed that way, then the logic needs to occur on the client (JavaScript). If however, the click of the `LinkButton` is supposed to postback to the server, then the place for the logic is on the server ...

Comment: still trying to get it to work. Had thought it had worked but it did not.

Answer (score 1):

using jquery it can be as easy as this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#<%=LinkButton1.ClientId %>").addClass(localStorage.style);
});

    $("#<%=LinkButton1.ClientId %>").click(function () {
          $(this).parent("li").addClass("selected");
           localStorage.style="selected";
        });
```

Comment: I also tried your method but, I found that style would change but then immediately changed back to it's original state. I'm guessing this is because of the page doing a postback?

Comment: you can try the above edit not sure if it the best way but try it

Comment: If you don't want the postback, do a return false in javascript and it will prevent the postback from occuring. Thus making this answer workable.